# Blackberry 10 Android App "has stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have an Android application that works quite well on Android devices up to 4.2.2. I packaged the application to use in Blackberry 10 and for the most part it works.

There is one transition that does not work.  I have custom buttons created as RelativeLayouts and when these are clicked they perform a background task and then start a new Activity:

```
MessageSummaryPanel.this.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(messageDetails);
```

Is there something that would cause the app to stop in BB10 and not Android that I am not aware of.

I am using the BB10 plugin for Eclipse and the BB10 simulator

Comment: I would search for possible NullPointer arising from this statement. Could you add some more code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Crashlytics as my crash reporting library in Android, and it also works when the app has been ported to BB10.

It will give you the correct stack trace of the error (even if you use ProGuard).